# Convert base Exception into HttpException

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I'm developing ASP.Net application and I'm currently struggling with exception handling. I've already managed to do proper exception handling but I don't really know how to handle internal errors that are not suitable for UI.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Error(ex);
    Response.Clear();

    HttpException httpEx = ex as HttpException;
    if (httpEx == null)
    {
        switch(ex.GetType())
        {
            //Convert ex into httpexception 
            //with statuscode that depends on the exception type
        }
    }

    RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
    routeData.Values.Add("action", "Handler");
    routeData.Values.Add("exception", httpEx);
    Server.ClearError();
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

    var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
    var c = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory().CreateController(rc, "Error");
    c.Execute(rc);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to cast the exception to a `HttpException`?

Comment: just create an instance of HttpException, wrapping the original exception and passing the desired httpCode and message.

Comment: @larsbe, becouse I want to pass it to the view that manage exceptions and I need statuscode for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to cast your exception to a `HttpException` just try to create a new `HttpException` with the original exception as the inner one:

```
HttpException httpEx = new HttpException(500, msg, ex);
```