# Why am I getting a missing namespace error in my Web API project for 'HttpException'

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces

Following the ASP.NET Web Api 2 Building a REST Service from Start to Finish book, I've come across a namespace error that I can't resolve specifially for the HttpException reference.

`var httpException = exception as HttpException;`

I'm using C# and I've only seen that style used in VB.NET so there may be some issue with what syntax style is expected. The correction suggestion keeps trying to lowercase the h to make httpException, but the *HttpException* is expected

Here is the full code:

```
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Web; // bad practice: not usually supposed to be used on non 
    // web application projects
    using System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling;
    using WebApi2Book.Data.Exceptions;

    namespace WebApi2Book.Web.Common.ErrorHandling
    {
    public class GlobalExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
    {
        public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
        {
            var exception = context.Exception;

            var httpException = exception as HttpException; <- red squiggle
            if (httpException != null)
            {
                context.Result = new SimpleErrorResult(context.Request, (HttpStatusCode)httpException.GetHttpCode(), httpException.Message);
                return;
            }
            if (exception is RootObjectNotFoundException)
            {
                context.Result = new SimpleErrorResult(context.Request, HttpStatusCode.NotFound, exception.Message);
                return;
            }
            if (exception is ChildObjectNotFoundException)
            {
                context.Result = new SimpleErrorResult(context.Request, HttpStatusCode.Conflict, exception.Message);
                return;
            }
            context.Result = new SimpleErrorResult(context.Request, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, exception.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your exact error message?

Comment: This might help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45615302/convert-base-exception-into-httpexception
With
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpexception.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_HttpException__ctor_System_Int32_System_String_System_Exception_

Comment: @DavidG The type or namespace 'HttpException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

Comment: @AdamMartin that is a great resource but I don't know if I should implement my own fix since I'm following a book to learn, I'm hoping for a framework or syntax answer

Comment: Which framework is your project targeting?

Comment: @jonsca Target Framework: .NET Standard 2.0

Comment: @springathing .NET Standard is meant to be a "lowest common denominator" that includes only a subset of the .NET libraries that are common to the different versions of the framework.  If you target one of the 4.x .NET frameworks you should still have access to the full System.Web.

Comment: @jonsca The strange thing is when I was creating my projects they were supposed to be targeting 4.6.x, the 4.x ones aren't even an option in the project properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mentioned in the comments that you are targeting .NET Standard 2.0.  Much of the `System.Web` library has been eliminated (largely due to it not being a part of .NET Core, I believe).

You should target a 4.x framework to regain access to this class.  If you don't have any other web project types besides .NET Core and .NET Standard, you will need to go to the Visual Studio Installer and select the 4.x framework support.

Select "Modify" under the dropdown next to your VS version, 
[image]

then select the checkbox for ASP.NET and Web Development
[image]

Then, in your New Project dialog, you should see this option:

[image]